# Do the functions of each class have function pointers inside the objects of that class?

Tags: c++

When I do something like this:

```
student1.foo();    // student1 is an object of class Student
```

Is there a function pointer that points to the `foo()` function inside the `student1` object, are does the compiler simply generate machine code that calls `Student.foo()` without actually storing a function pointer for the `foo()` function inside each `Student` object?

Comment: what's the difference? EDIT: oh, I see. No, it would not allocate space for member function pointer per object.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. are you asken about virtual tables?

Comment: Are you talking about the `this` pointer which is passed as a hidden argument to every member function..?

Comment: look at the assemble code for [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5zUa3q) and you can see that the compiler calls the same Foo for all instances of the sam class unless you have inheritance and virtual function

Comment: the compiler writes code in such a way that all necessary registers are saved and a new stack is created.. and then `call` the function `student::foo` (assuming student is your class) with the pointer `student1` (this) as the first parameter to that function.

Answer (score 0):

No, function pointers are not involved here. In your case the `foo()` function is called and a pointer to the `student1` object is passed to that function. That pointer is referred to as `this` in the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not require instances of a class to contain pointers to its members at all.

Beyond that, it is a choice for the implementation (like the compiler).

Practically, no implementation stores a pointer to a non-virtual member function within instances of a class.    All the compiler needs is the address (or  reference) to the object and - with visibility of the class definition - it can emit code to call the function correctly.

One way of supporting virtual functions - used in most, if not all implementations, in practice - involves virtual function tables (sometimes known as vtables for short).   A vtable is notionally a data structure that contains a set of pointers to a set of virtual functions, and every object contains a vtable (or a pointer/reference to one).    Calling a virtual function then involves looking up the function to call, and calling it while supplying the `this` pointer and arguments as needed. This is a common implementation choice because it is reasonably efficient by various measures, but not actually required by the standard (which only requires that `object->some_virtual_function()` resolves to the most derived version of the virtual function).   Details get more complicated if using multiple inheritance, since the object may contain distinct vtables for different inherited bases, but the basic approach is the same.

None of that prevents a programmer manually defining members of the class that point to other members (either normal pointers, or "pointer to member").